# Pass Data To Child Component Typescript Error on Next.JS 14 build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I understand there are a lot of similar questions, but somehow I'm not able to get my code working.

Recently started learning typescript and I'm not able to pass a single data to the child component.

Code works on dev (there is no visual studio warning or error) but during the build, **it fails.**

Here is my simplified code:

**Parent is `Layout.tsx`**

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import Page from "./page";
// import { getData } from "../actions/first";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      layout2
      <Page name="HI" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**and Child is `page.tsx`:**

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  name: string;
};

const Page: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
// export default function Page({ name }: { name: string }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Test Page 1</p>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Looking for help, not able to find the reason/error on my code.

These both are server components.

Thanks!

***Edit***

The error is page.tsx has invalid default export, `Type Props` is not valid.

and if I write my child component like this -

```
export default function Page({ name }: { name: string }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error is -> page has an invalid default export, type "{name:string}" is not valid.

Comment: What's the error when building?

Comment: @RobertRendell page,tsx has an invalid default export. Type Props is not valid.

Comment: Both layout and child files should have `.tsx` as a file extension. But it seems like you named the layout file with `.js` which is not valid.

Comment: @0xKevin it is actually .tsx for both the files.  sorry that I wrote .js here, edited now.

Comment: There are 2 points that I'm seeing from your shared code. 1 - your layout file must accept a children prop, but you're missing it. 2 - in your page file, you don't need to define Props type. Just aceept data without defining Props type like: `export default function Page({ name }) { ... }`

Comment: @0xKevin let me try this and will update you.

Comment: @0xKevin finally got it working, after 2 days of trial, thanks for the suggestion, I will write a detailed answer soon.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

So this is my assumption of how next.js works, the relation between custom Layout.tsx and page.tsx file.

The layout component needs to have a children props. this children props is nothing but next.js by default renders page.tsx component as a children of layout.tsx.
(this mean we don't have to import page.tsx in our layout page).

the correct syntax for layout.tsx is  -

```
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode })   {
    return (
     <div>
      {children}
     </div>
    );
 }
```

and it will render the content of page.tsx

Now we may create another component, let us call it Abc.tsx . this component needs to be imported into our layout component and we can pass the props to this component.

So, Abc.tsx file is -

```
import React from "react";

export default function Abc({ name }: { name: string }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and we can write our layout comp as -

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import Abc from "./abc";

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode })  {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      <Abc name={"TestData"} />
    </div>
    );
  }
```

This whole thing is working now for me,

How to pass props to **{children}**  is a different concept. (to page.tsx file)

This way we can have our app into multiple sections and create a unique layout for each section.